# ASP.NET CheckBox Value doesn't change

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, triggers

I have the following code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="true" RenderMode="Inline">
    <ContentTemplate> 
       <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxTel" Text="Phone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </td>
       </tr>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckBoxTel" EventName="CheckedChanged" />                   
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I would like to not refresh the page when a checkbox is checked or unchecked that's why I use a trigger but I'm new to update panel and trigger and I'm not sure why when I click on my submit button that refreshes the page, the checkbox keeps unchecked even if I checked it. Do I have to bind something to the button ?

Here is the button code :

```
<asp:Button ID="Search" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Search_OnClick" />
```

Comment: May be it because your button isn't wrapped inside update panel that why there a full post back instead of partial.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me if there is a full post back after I click on the button. I just don't get why when I check my checkbox and then click on the button the following line of code shows me "false" : CheckBoxTel.Checked. I was thinking there might be something to do in the Page_Load.

Comment: Can you show where you are getting 'False' value.

Comment: I can't show the code but in the Search_OnClick function I am calling another method in which i want to do something (add the tag <th>, a new column to a table) if the checkbox is checked. I don't know if it is important to say but after the page is loaded, the checkbox is reseted to false. Something else that might be the problem is that I have a form with runat server attribute covering all the body tag but I also have forms inside it without the attribute runat server. Is it possible that only the first form is sent ? Should i remove the forms and keep only one ?

Comment: I have modified my code so I have only one form left and it is now working. Checkbox value is updated and set to true after I cheked it and clicked on the button. Thanks for taking some time on my problem.